# Better way to write joins

Tags: sql, excel, join, openedge, progress-db

I have put together the below statement i know that is is long and when originally created this was done in Microsoft Query so it does not do proper joins. What would be the best way to do the joins? I am working form a Progress database pulling the query directly into Excel.

```
SELECT 

Company_0.CoaCompanyName
,Company_0.CompanyID
, SopOrder_0.SooOrderDate
, Count(DISTINCT SopOrder_0.SooParentOrderReference) AS 'Orders'
, SUM(CASE WHEN SopOrder_0.SooOrderNumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Order Items'
, SUM(SopOrderItem_0.SoiValue) AS 'Order Value'
,(CASE WHEN SopOrder_0.SooParentOrderReference LIKE 'INT%' THEN 'INT' ELSE 'WEB' END) AS 'OrderType'
,(CASE WHEN Company_0.CompanyID IN (7942127,7950986,7955733,7955922,7956194,9166261,9167003,9167015,9167821,9168185,71108583,153823092,239325930,248936585,484537132,484562257,492867962,497661455) THEN 'Blue'
WHEN Company_0.CompanyID IN (7941326,7942863,7951258,7985610,8054787,8059257,8071540,9165903,9166385,9167199,9167239,9168059,9168092,9168309,9176378,87527213,137281027,141171263,187080272,206550932,206567582,206653611,261731657,291593618,332362604,335570516,335584157,335636738,335780251,337122588,337321409,337495183,338813206,339895994,340298080,345796060,352141359,355461038,367864957,368581219,380483346,388367115,394146462,420408339,422017277,482844312,484535001,490217153,500689836,530081645,626234139,626240584) THEN 'Green'
WHEN Company_0.CompanyID IN (7937292,10245154,12081274,69822571,244700075,348041567,350378220,369621811,492752273,492810572,495589681,497434153,497436315,497447995,497501580,497640064,497687156,524765392,543828284,544700552,577727766) THEN 'InterGroup'
WHEN Company_0.CompanyID IN (390329465,7939077,7939153,7939643,7941067,7941441,7948530,7954220,7954463,7967527,7967564,7967581,7967598,7967615,7967632,7972683,8010930,8055406,8145843,8298176,8555272,8557302,9165068,9165858,9165941,9165990,9166173,9166187,9166221,9166275,9166408,9166733,9166771,9166817,9166839,9167420,9167441,9167462,9167785,9167852,9167909,9168157,9168555,9168579,9168656,9168739,9872539,12079739,12085840,12090519,13801203,18579021,34030102,34324342,34387765,58651641,70893751,75695054,94804172,104968711,124831809,135938287,140557486,155773253,170949925,181601032,181716302,181882963,185256839,191685680,195478063,196446370,196668711,198801097,203101459,217752161,230159704,241060623,246550560,248306594,252917455,272669511,275471863,294618970,302920726,305222885,327567159,328144055,330709733,332849207,337549264,337731848,340242946,340680961,348334040,349629764,350498903,357825478,358320695,362987262,391331042,400869283,401815465,428957939,429336116,432275881,432279597,443630203,450567544,453988169,484512602,484520712,484533033,484534199,484535847,484544428,484545125,484547021,484553137,487900076,491242614,492744710,492787927,492799726,492866923,497444080,497483018,499764323,501511914,502110491,503540613,503636535,504164530,508658401,508888435,508928101,511003520,513859770,517955290,519195801,523016532,527792211,542417909,547466213,549446456,553500528,553903855,557276314,558877342,575056260,591279217,592140130,600576497,602002033,615324116,626695365,633057105) THEN 'RED'
WHEN Company_0.CompanyID IN (7939412,7939655,7941712,8054218,8054544,8054567,8059303,9166056,9168330,94823141,303192985,337650213,340055053,357598514,506835671,512310844,574877608,576590130,603197632) THEN 'Yellow'
ELSE NULL
END) AS 'Cell'
,(CASE 
WHEN SopOrderItem.SoiProcessMethod = 0 AND SopOrderItem.SoiReplenishmentOrder = 1 AND SopProduct.SopPrePostPaid = 0 THEN 'Replenishment Pay on Replenishment'
WHEN SopOrderItem.SoiProcessMethod = 0 AND SopOrderItem.SoiReplenishmentOrder = 1 AND SopProduct.SopPrePostPaid <> 0 THEN 'Replenishment Pay on Delivery'
WHEN SopOrderItem.SoiProcessMethod = 0 AND SopOrderItem.SoiReplenishmentOrder = 0 THEN 'Call off'
WHEN SopOrderItem.SoiProcessMethod = 1 THEN 'On Demand'
WHEN SopOrderItem.SoiProcessMethod = 2 THEN 'Personalised'
ELSE 'Service'
END) AS 'OrderMethod'

FROM 

SBS.PUB.Company Company_0
, SBS.PUB.SopOrder SopOrder_0
, SBS.PUB.SopOrderItem SopOrderItem_0
, SBS.PUB.SopProduct SopProduct_0

WHERE 

SopOrder_0.SopOrderID = SopOrderItem_0.SopOrderID 
AND Company_0.CompanyID = SopOrder_0.CompanyID
AND SopOrderItem_0.SopProductID = SopProduct_0.SopProductID
AND SopOrder_0.SooOrderDate > '2018-01-01'
AND Company_0.CompanyID  <> '66643115'


GROUP BY 

Company_0.CoaCompanyName
,SopOrder_0.SooOrderDate
,Company_0.CompanyID
,Cell
,OrderType
,OrderMethod
```

My thoughts where that it should look something like this:

```
FROM 

SBS.PUB.SopOrderItem SopOrderItem_0
INNER JOIN SBS.PUB.Company Company_0 ON  SopOrder_0.CompanyID = Company_0.CompanyID
INNER JOIN SBS.PUB.SopOrder SopOrder_0 ON SopOrderItem_0.SopOrderItemID = SopOrder_0.SopOrderID
LEFT JOIN SBS.PUB.SopProduct SopProduct_0 ON SopOrderItem_0.SopProductID =  SopProduct_0.SopProductID


WHERE
```

But when i try to return this i get an error reading that `SopOrder_0.CompanyID` can not be found even though i know it is in the table as the original basic join query worked.

Comment: The proper way to express joins is to use `JOIN` with the appropriate `ON` clause.

Comment: The JOIN chain is evaluated from left to right, and an ON clause may only contain columns from tables to the left. (While the WHERE clause can contain columns from all tables in the FROM clause.)

Comment: Why do you think the original has anything to do with left join? Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join. Also: Please in code questions give a [mcve]. Also: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal and/or error message, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT ....
FROM SBS.PUB.Company Company_0
JOIN SBS.PUB.SopOrder SopOrder_0
    ON Company_0.CompanyID = SopOrder_0.CompanyID
JOIN SBS.PUB.SopOrderItem SopOrderItem_0
    ON SopOrder_0.SopOrderID = SopOrderItem_0.SopOrderID
JOIN SBS.PUB.SopProduct SopProduct_0
    ON SopOrderItem_0.SopProductID = SopProduct_0.SopProductID

WHERE SopOrder_0.SooOrderDate > '2018-01-01'
AND Company_0.CompanyID  <> '66643115'
```

I saw no left joins in your original queries so I've translated all joins into inner joins.

Answer (score 1):

This should work - replace your FROM and WHERE blocks of code with:

```
FROM SBS.PUB.Company Company_0
INNER JOIN SBS.PUB.SopOrder SopOrder_0 ON company_o.companyid = soporder_o.soporderid
INNER JOIN SBS.PUB.SopOrderItem SopOrderItem_0 ON sopOrderiterm_o.soporderid = 
SopOrder_0.SopOrderID
INNER JOIN SBS.PUB.SopProduct SopProduct_0 ON SopOrderItem_0.SopProductID 
=SopProduct_0.SopProductID

WHERE SopOrder_0.SooOrderDate > '2018-01-01'
AND Company_0.CompanyID <> '66643115'
```